# Customizing shopping cart magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, shopping-cart-price-rules, marketplace

I work in project with marketplace extension, and I like to Customize the shopping cart to add some information like, the name of the vendor and it's logo, but I can't do that.

Someone please can help me, how can I do that ?

Comment: Need more information, like in shopping cart which area to add text or override something?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I like to sort article by Seller and add some information as name of seller : because I work with marketplace,